# Multi thread with window service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

Can I use the same process in multiple threads?

There are 5 categories:

- 1 category - 100000 mail send
- 2 category - 10000 mail send
- 3 category - 200000 mail send
- 4 category - 1000 mail send
- 5 category - 300000 mail send

that are using *two threads*.

Thread time to send mail for each cateogry: [Thread 1] Took 40 mins for category 1; [Thread 2] took 10 mins for category 2
[Category 3] should be picked up by Thread 2 and after that randomly taking other categories. I am using Asp.net with Window service in backgorund process.

This is the method to get the mail detail : `SendNewsLatterStatus`
so that [Category 3] is continuing with Thread 2 and after that randomly taking 
category in Thread .. 
In asp.net with Window service in backgorund process.

```
            NewsLatterThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendNewsLatterStatus));
            NewsLatterThread1.Name = "NewsLatter1";

            NewsLatterThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendNewsLatterStatus));
            NewsLatterThread2.Name = "NewsLatter2";

            NewsLatterThread1.Start();
            NewsLatterThread2.Start();

            NewsLatterThread1.Join();
            NewsLatterThread2.Join();

            NewsLatterThread1.Abort();
            NewsLatterThread2.Abort();
```

It's not properly working what is the mistake for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first clear out your concept of threading.

Read this http://www.albahari.com/threading/
This will surely clear air as well as will sort out your query.