# asp.net with Multiple thread using lock method

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

In that code i want to use Lock(this) method with using multiple thread in asp.net how to use it please explain me .   I want to use multiple thread in it method so please

```
    try
    {

        List<spEMS_MailSentSchedularListResult> dSchedularResult = ESManager.SendSchedularList();
        if (dSchedularResult != null)
        {
```

// Here I want to Lock method so can you please explain for that

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dSchedularResult.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    string strBody = "";

                    #region Creating STRBODY
                    strBody = AppConstant.MAIN_DIV_TAG_START + AppConstant.MAIN_TABLE_TAG_START_BGCOLOR.ToString() +

                                AppConstant.MAIN_TABLE_TR_TD_START_ALIGNMENT.ToString() +

                                AppConstant.MAIN_TABLE_TR_TD_END.ToString();
                    #endregion


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Page_Error(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Page_Error(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        ESManager = null;
    }
}
```

Now i hanve mentioned about where the code of lock is creating please Give me positive reply Thanks...

Comment: Saw your edit. Place the code you want to lock in the "// Your code to be locked" comment in the solution below.

Comment: Directly using that variable for                                   private static object syncRoot = new Object();                                                               and when i want to lock method but i want to use 2 thread in this same method so 1 record is lock for 2 nd thread while second is continuing for that ... so is it working ?

Comment: Now, I am confused, what you explained above is applying a lock on piece of code so multiple threads can use it without problem and this is the way as I showed. Now, did I understand it correctly !?

Comment: hi milind what i exactly need this is the method and of calling to send a mail and another link for what i am using thread in it . so please can you check it .         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115907/multi-thread-with-window-service-in-asp-net/13116564#13116564

Answer (score 1):

You have not made clear which part of the code you want to lock.

General use of lock is like this

Define a class level variable

```
private static object syncRoot = new Object();
```

and when you are using

```
lock (syncRoot)
{
// your code to be locked.
}
```

Hope that helps

Milind